# Querying SQL Tables if they exists. Delete contents of table if they do Create table if if they don't

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am making a simple C# program that pulls out folder names and file names and puts them into a SQL Database.

I am making a method in which I would like if these exist to be checked. However Instead of dropping the whole table I would rather just delete the items in it. And if it does not exist to create the table.

This is what I have so far but it does not seem to be deleting the table regardless.

Any help is appreciated.

```
static void CheckTablesExist() {
  try {
    // Build connection string
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder {
      DataSource = "WIN10-LAP-HJP",
      UserID = "sa",
      Password = "Mypassword123",
      InitialCatalog = "SAPExtract"
    };
    // Connect to SQL
    Console.Write("Connecting to SQL Server ... ");
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString)) {
      Console.WriteLine("Done.");
      Console.WriteLine("Checking If table dbo.FolderInfo");
      string queryCheckTable = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Product";
      using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryCheckTable, connection)) {
        command.Parameters.Add("@FolderID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = "dbo.FolderInfo";
        connection.Open();
      }
    }
  }
  catch (SqlException e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
  }
}
```

UPDATED to execute

```
      static void CheckTablesExist()
        {
            try
            {
                // Build connection string
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
                {
                    DataSource = "WIN10-LAP-HJP",
                    UserID = "sa",
                    Password = "Mypassword123",
                    InitialCatalog = "SAPExtract"
                };

                // Connect to SQL
                Console.Write("Connecting to SQL Server ... ");
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Checking If table dbo.FolderInfo");


                    string queryCheckTable = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS @FolderTable";

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryCheckTable, connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.Add("@FolderTable", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "dbo.FolderInfo";



                        connection.Open();

                        var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        // Check Error
                        if (result < 0)
                            Console.WriteLine("Error inserting data into Database!");

                    }
                }
            }

            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: you never actually execute the query...

Comment: So what you want to do has nothing with the question's title or the code. You want to *create* a table, not drop it. Query the table `sys.tables` to see whether those tables exist and execute `DELETE` if they do, `CREATE` with the full specification if they don't.

Comment: Sorry I have updated the title now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the query for `queryCheckTable` to:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('Your_Table_Name','U') IS  NULL)
BEGIN 
    --Add "TRUNCATE TABLE" query here
    --Note: Use "TRUNCATE" or "DELETE" instead of "DROP"
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --Add "CREATE TABLE" query here 
END
```

Comment: Could this all be contained within a string and used via c#?

Comment: Yes, you could wrap all this in the sql string variable